# Facebook Duckling error getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, duckling

i followed the following steps:

> apt-get install haskell-platform
>
> curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
>
> git clone https://github.com/facebookincubator/duckling.git
>
> stack setup
>
> stack build
>
> stack exec duckling-example-exe

and i get the following error any idea why?

> duckling-example-exe: /usr/share/zoneinfo/: getDirectoryContents:openDirStream: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Comment: Does the directory `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` exist?

Comment: Yes this was the issue, Ubuntu 16 removed it

Answer (score 4):

You might just need to apt-get install tzdata -- I was searching for where zoneinfo is supposed to come from, and I found reports that it was not installed by default anymore in Ubuntu 16.04. I don't see that it's a part of baseimage at all, so it's probably missing from your container.

from [source](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/415)